# [Vue warn]: Property or method "task" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.5, laravel-mix

I work with Laravel 5.5, Vue 2 and use Laravel-mix, i tried to render a list on input elements using Vue, but when i try this, the console return

**[Vue warn]: Property or method "task" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render**

This is my template, like a loop:

```
<template v-for="task in tasks">
    <div class="input-group mb-1">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <div class="input-group-text bg-white cursor-pointer checkbox">
                <span class="mdi mdi-crop-square"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="text" :id="task.id_task" class="form-control bg-white cursor-pointer task-clk" :value="task.name" @click="showTask"
            readonly>
    </div>
</template>
```

So, this is my Vue component

```
<script>
    function Task({id_task, name, status}) {
        this.id_task = id_task;
        this.name = name;
        this.status = status;
    }

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                tasks: []
            }
        },
        props: ['idList, id_task, name, status'],
        created() {
            this.getTasks();
        },
        methods: {
            getTasks() {
                window.axios.get('/api/get-tasks-by-list/' + this.idList).then(({data}) => {
                    data.tasks.forEach(task => {
                        this.tasks.push(new Task(task));
                    });
                });
            },
            showTask(ev) {
                var id = ev.currentTarget.id;
                console.log(id);
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

I really dont understand why this error.

Comment: change `<template v-for="task in tasks">` to `<template><div v-for="task in tasks">...</div></template>`

Comment: If you've added a `v-for` to your base template, then Sphinx's advice is almost correct. The base template tag for a .vue single-file component is specifically used by `vue-loader` and behaves differently from normal `<template>` tags. It is just a placeholder for the content of the template for your vue component and will ignore all directives assigned to it. Additionally though, a vue component must have a single root element for its template definition, so you'll need to do something like this:  `<template><div><template v-for="task in tasks">...</template></div></template>`

Comment: Thanks!, thats works for me, the error did are the `v-for` property in `<template>` tag